# Using NSCache instead of NSMutable dictionary for reclaimable data

Tags: nsmutabledictionary, didreceivememorywarning, nscache

I am using around 25 **NSMutableDictionary** in my singleton class to hold the data from web services. When I try to access those dictionaries if those dictionaries are nil, service will be invoked and dictionaries will be filled.

**My questions are**

1. When my app receives DidReceivedMemoryWarning, Will those dictionaries be released?
2. If it is not released, can i explicitly set those dictionaries to nil when app receives memory warning message?
3. Instead of doing step1 and step2, can i use **NSCache** instead of **NSMutableDictionary** as NSCache will be released automatically when app receives memory warning?